# How to use both modal and modalless dialog created from main window in WinForms (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms

I've an application that has many modal windows. But, one window is modal less and use for diagnostic update. Both windows are created from main application window (parent). So, when I open the diagnostic window (modal less) and then open a modal window, I can't select and handle diagnostic window.

Is there any way to handle both modal and modal less window with both of them are displayed?

Thanks.

Comment: That's strange, are you parenting your modal windows to your original application window or to the moadl less window?

Comment: A modal window is meant to block the executing workflow until you complete the task assigned to the modal window. If you want to work with multiple child windows at the same time then they will need to be modal less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, anytime that you create a modal window, it becomes the central focus of your application. Any clicks outside of the modal window will not be registered. If you really need both to be accessible, then you will have to make both modeless.

Answer (score 0):

None that I'm familiar with. You display a modal dialog (i.e. maybe a confirmation box) because you want the user to deal with it before working with the rest of the application. A modeless form (i.e. a floating toolbox) is one that you want the user to be able to access while still working with the main program.

Here's a [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) for an older version of Visual Studio, but the content is still valid.

Comment: Modal dialog with component settings and when the settings are changed, changes are updated in the diagnostic window.